# How to read data from an external array PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, get, external

I have two files:
config.php:

```
$config["stations"]["aacplus"] = array( 
    "host" => "11.111.111.111",
    "port" => "9999",
    "password" => "aacplusv3",
            "logo" => "http://cassianohost.com.br/amostra/sualogo.jpg"
);
$config["stations"]["aacplus"] = array( 
    "host" => "22.222.222.222.222",
    "port" => "8888",
    "password" => "aacplusv3",
            "logo" => "http://cassianohost.com.br/amostra/sualogo.jpg"
);`
```

And I have an index:

```
    <?      
session_start();
$porta = $_SESSION["config"]["array"]["stations"]["aacplus"]["$port"];
include("config.php");?>
<html>
Porta: <?echo $port ?>
```

How can I capture the port that is in the index php config?

Comment: include your config file before the `$porta = ...` line? You also know your second config array will completely overwrite your first right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two arrays are overwriting each other. If you want them to be inline you need to do

```
$config["stations"]["aacplus"] = array();
$config["stations"]["aacplus"][] = array( 
    "host" => "11.111.111.111",
    "port" => "9999",
    "password" => "aacplusv3",
            "logo" => "http://cassianohost.com.br/amostra/sualogo.jpg"
);
$config["stations"]["aacplus"][] = array( 
    "host" => "22.222.222.222.222",
    "port" => "8888",
    "password" => "aacplusv3",
            "logo" => "http://cassianohost.com.br/amostra/sualogo.jpg"
);
```

Then you could do

```
echo $config["stations"]["aacplus"][0]["port"];
echo $config["stations"]["aacplus"][1]["port"];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a multi-dimension array, so you can access the third level like:

```
$Port = $config["stations"]["aacplus"]["port"];
```

However, a note of warning, you are overwriting the `$config` with the second array, so only one port is accessible. To avoid this, do:

```
//                      note: vv
$config["stations"]["aacplus"][] = array( 
"host" => "11.111.111.111",
"port" => "9999",
"password" => "aacplusv3",
        "logo" => "http://cassianohost.com.br/amostra/sualogo.jpg"
);
$config["stations"]["aacplus"][] = array( 
"host" => "22.222.222.222.222",
"port" => "8888",
"password" => "aacplusv3",
        "logo" => "http://cassianohost.com.br/amostra/sualogo.jpg"
);
```

And then you can have a simple array with ports like:

```
$Ports = array();
foreach ($config["stations"]["aacplus"] as $Station)
  {
  $Ports[] = $Station["port"];
  }
```

Then in your index you can display all ports:

```
foreach ($Ports as $Port)
  {
  echo $Port . "<br>";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong `["$port"];` do not include the `$` because you are trying to get the value on the array that has a key named `port`

```
$configport = $config["stations"]["aacplus"];
echo $configport["port"];
```